# How to access the Selenium object from Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

I'm using Cucumber with JUnit as a front end to drive my tests and Selenium as a back end to interact with a browser.

For the most part I access Selenium by using the web driver. The code looks something like:

```
WebDriver driver = WebDriverFactory.getDriver();
driver.findElement()....
```

For most of my testing this is OK, However there are some method on the com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium Object that I'd also like to use. What I can't seem to find is a suitable getter that returns this Object. Any idea how this is supposed to be done?

Comment: It's unclear from your question what you're looking for. Why do you want a method from Selenium that returns a WebDriver? Also, which version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm using selenium 2 and I'm currently I'm using org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver to drive my tests and for the most part this works well. However I'd *also* like access to a com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium object. This is because there are a load of methods in this class that the WebDriver doesn't have and I'd really like to use. For example, I'd wanted to use Selenium.getLog() to get a better idea on what's going on. Also I'd like to monitor AJAX calls - This forum describes what I have to do, but the answers assume I have access to a Selenium Object (but I don't).

Comment: @Stormcloud: You are talking about Selenium RC to use. You can use Selenium instance in RC, WebDriver instance in Selenium 2 (known as WebDriver). But, Selenium 2 (WebDriver) is the successor of Selenium RC. Why are you thinking to use old one?

Comment: My suggestion is to use Selenium 2 (WebDriver) instead of using Selenium 1 (Selenium RC)